# Calling WMS layer using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wms, getmap

I am trying to call a WMS using OpenLayers. I have wrote the code but somehow I think I am missing something here.

My code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers WMS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'EPSG: 4326', 
        extent: [-179106.47, 3835054.33, 1457898.22, 4881225.40]
    });

    // wms
    //http://172.61.25.57:8080/geoserver/arcs_charts/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=arcs_charts%3A1239-0&bbox=-4.0%2C58.28333333333333%2C0.1985833333333341%2C61.41675&width=768&height=573&srs=EPSG%3A4326&format=application/openlayers -->
    // source
    var layerSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://172.61.25.57:8080/geoserver/arcs_charts/wms?',
        params: {'VERSION': '1.1.0',
                'LAYERS': 'arcs_charts:1239-0', 
                'TILED': true,
                'bbox': [-4.0,58.28333333333333,0.1985833333333341,61.41675], // GeoServer bbox or extent in EPGS: 5255 - read from url in GeoServer WMS
                'CRS': 'EPSG:4326',
                'HEIGHT': 573,
                'width':768,
                'FORMAT': 'application/openlayers'},
        serverType: 'geoserver',
    });


    // layer
    var layerLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        layer:'nameOfLayer',
        visible: false,
        preload: Infinity,
        source: layerSource 
    });

    // view
    var olview = new ol.View({
        projection: projection,
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
        extent: projection.getExtent(),
        zoom: 1.5
    })

    // map
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        renderer: 'canvas', // Force the renderer to be used
        view: olview,
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        layers: [layerLayer], 
        controls: ol.control.defaults(),
        logo: false
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: @IanTurton, Correct me if I am wrong! I have wrote the question properly and what I am trying to achieve here plus I have wrote the code snippet what I have tried. Is this not how should I post the Question!!

Comment: you missed out the what goes wrong part

Comment: Format OpenLayers is incorrect you need png.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the layers property only once, and it should contain all the layers, so

```
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    layers: [layerLayer],
```

becomes

```
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }),
      layerLayer
    ],
```

Also `visible: false,` means the layer will not be seen or loaded

Comment: I have added it but still  I have no response.. I am only able to view blue screen

Comment: That could be because the projection and coordinates are inconsistent.  The view `projection` is set to `EPSG:4326` (there should be no space) which is LonLat (so an extent greater [-180, -90, 180, 90] doesn't make sense) but you are calling `fromLonLat` which transforms to EPSG:3857?